# Regular expression remove full stop from bullet text

Tags: regex

I'm really struggling to work out how to remove the full stop from the following:

```
• this is a test bullet.<br>
• this is a test bullet 2.<br>
• this is a test bullet 3.<br>
```

It needs to only remove the full stops from the bullets as there are other paragraphs containing full stops and break returns.

Any help with this please?

The output would need to look like:

```
• this is a test bullet<br>
• this is a test bullet 2<br>
• this is a test bullet 3<br>
```

Comment: Which language/tool are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about, given that we should be able to use the bullet character, something simple like:

Find: `(•.*)\.(.*)`

Replace with: `$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the replaceAll method on the String object, like so:

```
String values = "• this is a test bullet.<br>\n" +
                  "• this is a test bullet 2.<br>\n" +
                  "• this is a test bullet 3.<br>";

values = values.replaceAll("(?i)\\.(?=<br>)", "");

// result:
// • this is a test bullet<br>
// • this is a test bullet 2<br>
// • this is a test bullet 3<br>
```

It will remove any full stops preceded by a `<br>` tag, and is case insensitive.

Explanation of regex:

Make pattern case insensitive:

```
(?i)
```

Find full stop (.):

```
\\.
```

Forward look ahead for `<br>` tag:

```
(?=<br>)
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex:

```
^(\s*•.*)\.$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

OR

Regex:

```
^\s*•.*\K\.$
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dR9cK6/3)